# selectOneMenu HTTP Status 500 - Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items"

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I'm trying to set a selectOneMenu List filled by Categorie name in Label & Categorie id in value i'm doing it this way :

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="categorie" value="#{adminRealisationController.categorie }">
            <c:forEach items="#{listeCats}" var="cat">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{cat.nom }" itemValue="#{cat.id }"/>
            </c:forEach>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

This listeCats is set a jsf bean here's what i'm doing to extract the list from db

```
BeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml")); 
        CategoriesPL C = (CategoriesPL) beanFactory.getBean("categoriesPL");


        setListeCats(C.findAll());
        titre="";slug="";categorie.setId(2);description="";

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("listeCats", getListeCats());

        return "nouveauView";
```

The property is set in the faces xml as Integer and I got this error When i try to submit the form:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's why `f:selectItems` exists, you should replace this

```
 <c:forEach items="#{listeCats}" var="cat">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{cat.nom }" itemValue="#{cat.id }"/>
 </c:forEach>
```

by this (when using JSF 2.0)

```
<f:selectItems value="#{listeCats}" var="cat" itemLabel="#{cat.nom}" itemValue="#{cat.id}" />
```

or by this (when using JSF 1.X)

```
<f:selectItems value="#{listeCats}" />
```

In the later, you will also need to return a `List<SelectItem>` :

```
public List<SelectItem> getListeCats()
{
    List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList();

    items.add(new SelectItem("value","label"));

    return items;
}
```

Note : this is only an example, it is not efficient at all. The only thing to remember is that you need to convert your `Object` list into `SelectItem`. Also, the `value="#{adminRealisationController.categorie}"` will receive a `String` and not your `Object`, so you will need to convert it.

**More info :**

- [JSF 2.0 f:selectItems](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html)
- [JSF 1.X f:selectItems](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/f/selectItems.html)
- [Our selectOneMenu wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Comment: Then i get  "Attribute var invalid for tag selectItems according to TLD". It's because i'm using JSF 1.2 ??